# Get price from Excel and need to calculate the values using POI

Tags: java, selenium, apache-poi

In the excel there is one column Value1, which contains prices.. like $2789.98, $32321.45. I want to get those values and need to do addition , ex: 2789.98+32321.45.

```
public void testData() throws IOException {
    Object[] calc = this.readExcelByColName("Calculations");
    for (int i = 1; i < calc.length; i++) {
        String string = (String) calc[i-1];
        string = string.replaceAll("\\s", "");
        String[] parts = string.split("(\\=)");
        String[] parts1 = parts[0].split("(\\+)");
        DataFormatter df = new DataFormatter();
        if (parts.length == 2 && parts1.length > 1) {
            String value1 = df.formatCellValue(this.sheet.getRow(i).getCell(2));
            String value2 = df.formatCellValue(this.sheet.getRow(i).getCell(3));
            String value3 = df.formatCellValue(this.sheet.getRow(i).getCell(4));
            float result= (Float.parseFloat(value1.toString().substring(1).replaceAll(",", "")) + Float.parseFloat(value2.toString().substring(1).replaceAll(",", "")));
            if (result == Float.parseFloat(value3.toString().substring(1).replaceAll(",", ""))) {                   
                this.sheet.getRow(i).getCell(5).setCellValue("Pass");
            } else {
                this.sheet.getRow(i).getCell(5).setCellValue("Fail");
            }
```

Comment: I can able to get price with $ sign and removing that using substring, and then converting to integer, but in if (result == Integer.parseInt(value3)) { condition, It doesn't adding both the values in the result variable.

Comment: After running int result= Integer.parseInt(value1.toString().substring(1))+Integer.parseInt(value2.toString().substring(1)) the Test case is getting failing.

Comment: Its not returning any thing, out TC is getting fail. It seems there is an problem with conversions. I have checked converting to double but didn't work.

Comment: Im using this code value1.toString().substring(1) for reading data from index1..

Comment: giving the price with out $ like this 2,005.55

Comment: yes..removed it, however i cannot able to do parsing.

Comment: There is [Cell.getNumericCellValue](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getNumericCellValue%28%29) which returns a `double`. So no need getting a `String` via `DataFormatter` and then converting this `String` into a number.

Comment: using float, i m getting the values, but when I am doing addition its saying NumberFormatException.

Comment: Updated Please check

Comment: Put all 3 in separate variable and see which conversion fails and why

Comment: All 3 are converting correctly but the problem might be in the addition +.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using brackets "()" at wrong place

Try using below code-Just copy and paste

```
float result= Float.parseFloat(value1.toString().substring(1).replaceAll(",", "")) + Float.parseFloat(value2.toString().substring(1).replaceAll(",", ""));
```

Comment: Sure..I got one more problem. this.sheet.getRow(i).getCell(5).setCellValue("Pass"); I am not able to set cell value into my excel. what might be the problem.

Comment: Did you commit the change after updating the cell?

Comment: what does it mean Kapil? commiting means what exactly ur trying to say?

Comment: After updating the cell, you need to close the file. Something like this.sheet.close();

Comment: Yes I m calling this method saveAndCloseExcel(); which contains sheet.close

Comment: No Error Im getting..but after my TC run, I didnlt see the result cell value is written as Pass or Fail

Comment: Go through this URL - "http://www.techartifact.com/blogs/2013/10/update-or-edit-existing-excel-files-in-java-using-apache-poi.html" and verify if you are following the same process.